# how to make just first crossing when another condition executed

Tags: pine-script

I need to write this indicator :
MFI be under 20 and then cross over 20 ( it is main condition)
the buy signals appears when first cross up of RSI to rsiMA

I write this code :

```
    var sessionStart = false
if ta.crossover(mf,20)
    sessionStart := true
var rsicross = false
if rsi < rsiMA or rsi > rsiMA or ta.crossunder(rsi,rsiMA) 
    rsicross := false
if ta.crossover(rsi,rsiMA)
    rsicross := true
//====
buyCondition = sessionStart and rsicross
```

the problem that : all the rsi rsiMA crosses give buy signals because the main condition MFI crossed 20 before.
I need after MFI cross up 20 , just first rsi , rsiMA crossing give buy signals.
can someone help me please

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You will have to reset the buyCondition back to false when buy condition has occured. So that it will not give buy condition again until mf crossover occurs.

```
if buyCondition 
    sessionStart:false
```